# Toricelli and Bernoulli law - pressure definitions

Tags: pressure, bernoulli-equation

Torricelli's law can be derived from the Bernoulli equation

$P_1 + \rho g h_1 + \frac{1}{2}\rho v_1 = P_2 + \rho g h_2 + \frac{1}{2}\rho v_2^2$

However I don't know how to pressures $P_1$ and $P_2$ are **defined exactly**, so i can determine them precisely.

If we imagine the container with open top and a small hole near the bottom:

$P_1$ is the pressure acting on top of the fluid, so according to Pascal's law, every  point of the fluid is under same pressure $P_1$, plus some hydrostatic pressure.

However, the problem is $P_2$. Is it defined as the pressure from outside the small hole acting on the fluid (pushing it inside)? Or is it the pressure of fluid
$P_1 + \rho g h$ where $\rho g h$ is hydrostatic pressure?

Comment: Bernoulli's equation an expression of conservation of energy between two points in a fluid.  It does not consider the effects of friction or turbulence.  For a fluid flowing of of a hole, I would take the second point slightly outside of the hole where it is subject to atmospheric pressure.